# How to Translate excel PRODUCT formula

Tags: javascript, typescript, excel-formula

How to translate or restructure this `=(1-PRODUCT(K5:K14))` excel formula to javascript code.

I did this code in my own understanding but result is not correct  as i am expecting

```
exp_PRODUCT= [
  0.993758608,
  0.993847362,
  0.993934866,
  0.994021137,
  0.994106197,
  0.990118552,
  0.990226925,
  0.990334122,
  0.990440146,
  0.990545020
]

let result = 0.0;
  for(let prod of exp_PRODUCT){
    result = parseFloat(prod) + result;
  } 
 console.log('Total :' ,1-result )
```

expected answer is 7.XXXX%

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.  Product is multiplication, not addition.

```
exp_PRODUCT= [
0.993758608,
0.993847362,
0.993934866,
0.994021137,
0.994106197,
0.990118552,
0.990226925,
0.990334122,
0.990440146,
0.990545020
]

result = 1.0;
  for(let prod of exp_PRODUCT){
    result = parseFloat(prod) * result;

  } 
 console.log('Total :' ,1 - result )
```

Comment: thanks i will try this.. :) i did also multiplication but result is still incorrect .. :) will try your answer